# Post a message to friends inbox in facebook

Tags: facebook, api

How can i post a message to friends inbox in facebook. I know Facebook does not permit you to send messages to a user's inbox. As a result, there is a read_messages permission, but some application provide a functionality to invite friend, this invitaton send in friends inbox and notification email also send in frinds email ID, so have any possibility to send message in friend inbox on facebook.

Thanks

Comment: have to able to send message in Inbox of friends now....... and also I want to get the messages from my Inbox

Comment: hi @amit , can you share any link related to it and a link which show this...

Comment: Not now .. I think we cannot send message via FB API... and about getting message we may get but I haven't try .... for getting message http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=336279#p336279  but I still not tried it ....

Comment: for sending message you can try http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/liveMessage.send/ .. as it is old api you can use this in the way as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552556/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565512

Answer (score 1):

I am on a similar hunt, but here is something i know so far.

You can use fbml's fb:request-form to send invites, example below:

```
    <fb:fbml>
<fb:request-form
action="index.php" 
method="POST" 
invite="true" 
type="YOUR APP NAME" 
content="Your text goes here. <?php echo htmlentities("<fb:req-choice url=\"YOUR CANVAS URL\" label=\"Authorize My Application\"") ?>" > 
<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use YOUR APP NAME."> 
</fb:request-form>
</fb:fbml>
```

is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am using same code script but it send a application request with notification. Actually i want to send inbox message to facebook friend to invite on my site, because for the inbox message facebook sent a notification mail in user account. I don't know, Is that possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently unsupported capability although facebook has indicated they will support it in the not-so-distant future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a Facebook dialogue, but try this:

```
FB.ui({method: 'send', name: 'Facebook Dialogs', link:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/'});
```

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/514/